# Select random value from a enum

Tags: swift, enums

select random value from given enum

```
public class SwiftConfettiView: UIView {

    public enum ConfettiType {
        case confetti
        case triangle
        case star
        case diamond
        case image(UIImage)
    }
```

// usage in other class

```
    confettiView.type = .confetti
```

Would like to set randomly confettiView triangle, star,diamond,confetti

//This will not work

```
confetti.type =  ConfettiType.allCases.randomElement()!
```

**Type 'SwiftConfettiView.ConfettiType' has no member 'allCases'**

//So, all all confetti to an array list and load in from there!

```
var confettiList = [SwiftConfettiView.ConfettiType.confetti
    , SwiftConfettiView.ConfettiType.diamond
    ,        SwiftConfettiView.ConfettiType.triangle
    ,        SwiftConfettiView.ConfettiType.star
```

]

```
    confettiView.type = confettiList.randomElement()!
```

It's working properly!

is this approach is correct or wrong?

Comment: Don't use the SQL-style leading commas. It's a crutch for SQL's horrible design that disallows excess commas at the end of lists. Swift doesn't have this issue, so it doesn't need the crutch. Just put commas at the end of every list item.

Comment: Your issue here is that you need to conform to `CaseIterable` to get access to `allCases`, and that only works if your enum doesn't have associated values (because there's no way to enumerate all possible `UIImage`s. I'm not sure what the best work-around is.

Answer (score 5):

Here your enum is associated type. So if case of type image you have to provide a image as parameter. I have considered a default image.

```
extension ConfettiType: CaseIterable {
    static var allCases: [ConfettiType] {
        let img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "default_image")! // change as your expectation
        return [.confetti, .triangle, .star, .diamond, .image(img)]
    }    
}
let randomEnum = ConfettiType.allCases.randomElement()
```

Otherwise if your image type would be something like this `image(UIImage?)` then we can put `nil` as default value. In that case it would be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

@Alexander identified your issue in the comments: Your issue is that you need to conform to `CaseIterable` to get access to `allCases`, and that only works if your `enum` doesn't have associated values (because there's no way to enumerate all possible `UIImage`s).

Your workaround is fine, and it can be made nicer by taking advantage of Swift's type inference.

You might add a `randomChoice(from:)` function to your enum class that lets the caller specify which items to choose from.  Because of type inference, you can specify the cases without fully qualifying them (eg. `.confetti` and `.triange` is sufficient).

Here is a full example:

```
public class SwiftConfettiView: UIView {

    public enum ConfettiType {
        case confetti
        case triangle
        case star
        case diamond
        case image(UIImage)

        static func randomChoice(from choices: ConfettiType...) -> ConfettiType {
            return choices.randomElement()!
        }
    }

    func test() {
        for _ in 1...10 {
            let choice = ConfettiType.randomChoice(from: .confetti, .triangle, .star, .diamond)
            print(choice)
        }
    }
}

SwiftConfettiView().test()
```

> ```
> triangle
> triangle
> diamond
> diamond
> triangle
> star
> confetti
> confetti
> star
> triangle
> ```

**Notes:**

- Alternatively, you could have `randomChoice` take `[ConfettiType]`.  In that case, you need to decide how to handle an empty array (either return an optional so that you can return `nil` for an empty array, or provide a default value such as `.confetti` for that case).

  ```
  return choices.randomElement() ?? .confetti
  ```

  Taking an array gives you the ability to provide a default value, such as:

  ```
  static func randomChoice(from choices: [ConfettiType] = [.confetti, .triangle, .star, .diamond]) -> ConfettiType {
      return choices.randomElement() ?? .confetti
  }
  ```

  For example:

  ```
  // take the default values
  let choice = ConfettiType.randomChoice()

  // specify specific choices
  let choice = ConfettiType.randomChoice(from: [.star, .diamond])
  ```
- If you always just want to choose from those 4 enum values, you could just have `randomChoice` take no arguments and just hard code the choice from those 4 values.  In that case, `randomChoice` could be implemented as a computed property:

  ```
  static var randomChoice: ConfettiType { return [.confetti, .triangle, .star, .diamond].randomElement()! }
  ```

  and called like this:

  ```
  let choice = ConfettiType.randomChoice
  ```